# How to make a custom control validatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a custom control based on a `Panel`. It's merely a simple panel with 3 DropDownLists. If I add a `CompareValidator` to my WebForm and set the `ControlToValidate` property to the ID of my custom control I get the following error:

`Control '{0}' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of '{1}' cannot be validated.`

I understand why, the CompareValidator cannot sensibly validate anything against the `Panel`. So what do I need to add to my custom control to make it possible for a validator to be able to validate it?

I have tried adding a `Text` property to my Panel which returns a combination of the Text properties of the 3 DropDownLists. No avail.

I have tried looking for certain interfaces (`ITextControl`) that validatable controls (`TextBox`) implement and add them to my custom control. No avail.

How can I make my custom control based on a Panel, validatable by the regular .net validators? (RequiredFieldValidator, CompareValidator, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't already have it, you need to add the `ValidationProperty` attribute to your class so it knows which property to use for validation:

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:YourCustomControl runat=server></{0}:YourCustomControl>")]
public class YourCustomControl : WebControl
...
```

Comment: Yes, that does the trick! Thank you for your quick answer. :) Will accept in a few minutes.