# How to client side validate a custom control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, client-side

Following up on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521211/how-to-make-a-custom-control-validatable) about a custom control and validation I now have server side validation working but can't seem to figure out how to add the client side validation. I have to following control:

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:DateSelect runat=server></{0}:DateSelect>")]
public class DateSelect : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
{
 private DropDownList day;
 private DropDownList month;
 private DropDownList year;

 public DateSelect()
 {
    day = new DropDownList();
    /* some code to create items for 'day' here */
    Controls.Add(day);
    month = new DropDownList();
    /* some code to create items for 'month' here */
    Controls.Add(month);
    year = new DropDownList();
    /* some code to create items for 'year' here */
    Controls.Add(year);
 }


 public string Text
 {
    get
    {
        return year.Text + "-" + month.Text + "-" + day.Text;
    }
 }
}
```

On my webform I add this Control, add a CompareValidator in DataType operation to check against valid dates. I set the validator's `EnableClientScript` to `false` and the custom control is validated well on server side and provides the correct messages at the correct cases. However, as soon as I turn `EnableClientScript` to `true` the custom control is validated client side and produces an error message when there is in fact a valid date in the DropDownLists. I've been trying to figure out why and ended up at the following javascript generated by .net which I think never will come up with resulting in the correct value:

```
function ValidatorGetValueRecursive(control)
{
    if (typeof(control.value) == "string" && (control.type != "radio" || control.checked == true)) {
        return control.value;
    }
    var i, val;
    for (i = 0; i<control.childNodes.length; i++) {
        val = ValidatorGetValueRecursive(control.childNodes[i]);
        if (val != "") return val;
    }
    return "";
}
```

So I believe I have to add something to my custom control, perhaps a piece of javascript, that gets called as soon as the validator tries to validate my control and produces the correct value to validate against from the selected items of the three DropDownLists. I just have no clue where to add this script. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Because your control actually encompasses several server controls, I would suggest adding the client-side validators to the controls collection, much like you're doing with the other controls.

```
var ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.ID = "ddlDay";
Controls.Add(ddl);

var validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
val.ControlToValidate = ddl.ID;
val.ErrorMessage = "*"; //property to set this for all validators
val.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic; //property to set this for all validators
Controls.Add(validator);
```

After adding the validators, you can expose properties to apply to all of the validators in the control, like the validation group, error message, display type, etc.

**EDIT #1**

If you want to validate the combined input as one, use a `CustomValidator` and register the necessary client scripts through the control.

I haven't tested this at all, but below is a simple code example to demonstrate the concept. Obviously, you would build the validation function in code using a `StringBuilder` or something:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    clientValidate = function(source, args){

        var ddl1 = document.getElementById("<%= ddl1.ClientID %>");
        var ddl2 = document.getElementById("<%= ddl2.ClientID %>");

        if (ddl1.options[e.selectedIndex].value.length == 0)
            args.IsValid = false;
        if (ddl2.options[e.selectedIndex].value.length == 0)
            args.IsValid = false; 

    }
</script>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="MyCustomValidator" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid" 
    ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate" />
```

Here's are some articles that explain how to use a custom validator for client-side validation:

- [Custom Validator For Multiple Controls](http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2010/10/12/ASPNET-CustomValidator-that-validates-multiple-controls-using-both-Server-Side-and-Client-Side-scripting.aspx)
- [CustomValidator.ClientValidationFunction Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx)

**EDIT #2**

A little more reading has revealed that the `CustomValidator` should be compatible with your composite control.

Comment: ok, I understand what you are saying but how does this make the client side validator validate against a combination of the 3 DropDownList's selected items as a date? Also note that in my current setup the server side validation works fine.

Comment: If the combined input is what you're looking to validate, I would use a `CustomValidator`, and have your control insert the necessary client scripts to perform the validation.

Comment: I understand your points but prefer to approach the problem from the other way, namely adapting the custom control in such way that the CompareValidator works with it. The reason for this is that all controls and validators are dynamically created based on the fields and the datatype that the database expects. I think your solution is feasible but since the CompareValidator works server side, I have the feeling that it should be possible to make it work client side as well. I just don't know where to hook in.

Comment: @Bazzz: Setting the `ControlToValidate` property to the ID of your custom control doesn't work? What's happening when you do that?

Comment: @Bazzz: Also, see `Edit #2` in my answer. I think the `CustomValidator` will work fine with your custom control, and it's flexible enough to handle any type of validation, i.e. required field, compare, regex, etc.

Comment: setting the ControlToValidate property will 1) on server side function as intended, and 2) on client side validate against the text of the first DropDownList following the script I posted in my question. Of course this text being just the day part of the date, doesn't validate as a date and the error message is shown. I'm looking for a way to tell the CompareValidator to use another method of acquiring the value of my custom control. The script in my question is generated by asp.net. I'd prefer to avoid the CustomValidator if possible, as it requires me to make many changes to existing code.